# Phonegap - testing on samsung gallaxy S3

Tags: android, cordova, samsung-mobile

when looking into phonegap testing previously (I've looked into it and then got sidetracked for a year and now looking again) using my HTC Desire, I simply connected my device, clicked run as android in eclipse and then it would automatically run the app through my device.

But when trying on my new phone (SGS3),i get

```
[2012-11-27 07:48:18 - name] Android Launch!
[2012-11-27 07:48:18 - name] adb is running normally.
[2012-11-27 07:48:18 - name] Performing com.thing.name.name activity launch
[2012-11-27 07:48:18 - name] No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.
```

I have installed all drivers I can think of, even installed Kies and AllShare in case they came with any additional drivers but still the same thing.

Has anyone else come across this or know how to fix?

regards

Comment: Which OS are you running? which SGS3 build are you on?

Comment: Yes my SDK is updated, my SGS3 build is 4.1.1 jro03c.i9300xxdlj1

Comment: My Project Build Target is Android 4.0 as the next one up (from what I can see) is Android 4.1.2

Comment: Unknown sources and usb debugging activated?

Comment: Unknown sources yes, cant find debugging option...

Comment: Ah, found the option now (doh) and it is appearing in results for `adb devices`

Comment: you might want to stick that in an answer cause I guess thats what it was

Answer (score 1):

Search for Developer Options and enable `USB Debugging` and also make sure `Unknown Sources` is activated unless you already did.

**Android 4.2**

To make the developer options appaear in Android 4.2 you have to go to menu "About Telephone" and hammer on the build number a couple of times, till a toast tells you you are developer now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @dan's answer, you need to make sure the device is in USB MTP mode. (not Camera USB mode.)